# How to await for an asynchronous function in a normal function that is later going to turn to a coroutine in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm making a lisp dialect & I can't use any special syntax, only functions. I'm trying to add asynchronous programming.

I can turn a function into an asynchronous one using `asyncio.coroutine`.

```py
asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(lambda: print('Hello, world!'))())
```

I can also use asynchronous functions inside its body.

```py
asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(lambda: asyncio.sleep(1))())
```

but the problem with that is that they will run in the background. So if by using a `do` block, I execute `asyncio.sleep(1)` two times, the program will wait only 1 second since both of them are running in the background.

This is when `await`/`yield from` is used in asynchronous programming, but it's a syntax & not a function, hence I can't use it. I'm looking for a function alternative.

ChatGPT couldn't solve it & I've taken a look at the following StackOverFlow posts.

1. [How can I call an async function without await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630676/how-can-i-call-an-async-function-without-await)
2. [How to use await in a python lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746213/how-to-use-await-in-a-python-lambda)
3. [Can a Python coroutine be implemented without await or yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039539/can-a-python-coroutine-be-implemented-without-await-or-yield?rq=1)
4. [Automatic conversion of standard function into asynchronous function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70878454/automatic-conversion-of-standard-function-into-asynchronous-function-in-python)
5. [How to await a function in a normal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827531/how-to-await-a-function-in-a-normal-function)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can turn a function into an asynchronous one using `asyncio.coroutine`?"  There is no function `asyncio.coroutine`.  There is no point in turning a sync function into an async function unless there is something for the function to `await`.  Sync functions and async functions are different in design and purpose.  The async def declaration isn't what's important about an async function, it's the `await` expression inside the function.  Could you clarify this?

Comment: @PaulCornelius In the examples above `lambda: print('Hello, world!')` is a normal function, but using the `asyncio.coroutine` it will turn to an async one that will run in the background, without blocking

Comment: @PaulCornelius `coroutine` is a function in `asyncio` & it was used a lot with the `yield from` syntax, before python added the async/await syntax

Comment: @PaulCornelius I'm looking for an alternative of `await`/`yield from` that has the same semantics, but it's not a syntax, rather function

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've already find replacement for `async` keyword. now I need one for `await`

Comment: I see that asyncio.coroutine function was removed in Python3.11, which is the documentation I was looking at.  There is a similar function `types.coroutine`, but it converts generator functions into coroutines.  So, how is `asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(lambda: print('Hello, world!'))())` different from simply `print("Hello world")`?  You say it runs in the background, but what background is that?  The coroutine passed to asyncio.run() will start and end before your code advances to the next line.  Since it is a sync function in the first place, no multitasking can occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `asyncio.run()` function. Basically, it is `await` outside of asynchronous functions. For example,

```py
import asyncio

async def coro():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('hello')

asyncio.run(coro())
asyncio.run(coro())
```

will run both coroutines, one after another. It works the exact same way as `await`. For lambda functions, since `asyncio.coroutine(...)` yields a coroutine, you can use `asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(...))` to get your desired result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: not at all. I'm talking about using `await` inside of the function, without the syntax. using multiple `run`s is not allowed

Comment: `lambda: asyncio.run(...)`? I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: for better example. consider `coro` if it would turn to an asynchronous function, by using `coroutine`. how would I await for `sleep(1)`?

Comment: `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Comment: anyways. `run` isn't the answer

Comment: `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(...)`

Comment: What do you mean by "do" block?

Comment: `do` is a lisp function that executes multiple expressions & returns the last expression's result

Comment: I have `asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(func)())`, where `func`'s body has two `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))`. it gives me the error `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

Comment: But at that point, you don't need to wrap the `func` with `asyncio.coroutine`, you can just call it directly. Then it will not run in the background.

Comment: sorry, but that was an example & the above won't work on the real deal. I gotta explain a lot to fully understand you, why I can't use that. could you please focus on solving the problem, how I stated? by not modifying anything in the example, but just finding or making a function that can await the `asyncio.sleep`?

Comment: you could use `exec('async def func() {code here}')` I suppose, and then true await would be accessible. Since `exec()` just runs dynamically generated python, that should work. I do not know any other way to do it, I am sorry.

Comment: sorry, but can't do that either, unless python adds anonymous lambdas in the next update